# How to upload images to public folder in next js?

Tags: next.js

I want to upload images to a public folder, is this possible?

As of now, I am inserting images manually and deploying the application over and over again.

I badly need an easier way.

Based on the path URL, I will match the image in the public folder and then I will put in the image in the meta tag.